# Set progress to progress bar

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar, number-formatting

In activity, it has a `ListView` where the `ListView` item consists of 3 `TextView`(monthAndYear,totalUsed(RM20), and budget(RM123.0)),and a `ProgressBar`. I tried below code to show the progress in `ProgressBar`, but nothing happened.

[image]

```
 public void retrieveList(String name) {
        search.clear();
        database = mdb.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE__TASK + " WHERE Name = ? ", new String[]{name}, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int iD = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                String month = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Month"));
                double budget = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("Budget"));
                double totalUsed=cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("Total_Used"));
                if (adapter != null) {
                    adapter.add(iD,month,budget,totalUsed);
                    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Adapter**

```
 public void add(int id,String month,double budget,double used)
    {
        List obj = new List(id,month,budget,used);
        obj.setMonthYear("   " + month);
        obj.setBudget(budget);
        obj.setUsed(used);
        total = budget - used;
        obj.setProgress(total);
        search.add(obj);
        this. notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder =null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.expenses_adapter, null);
            holder= new ViewHolder();
            holder.monthAndYear = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.monthAndYear);
            holder.budget = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.budget);
            holder.amount=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.amount);
            holder.progressBar=(ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.downloadProgressBar);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.monthAndYear.setText(search.get(position).getMonthAndYear());
        holder.budget.setText("RM"+""+search.get(position).getBudget());
        holder.amount.setText("RM"+""+search.get(position).getUsed());
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView monthAndYear, budget,amount;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
    }
```

After I add   `holder.progressBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(total+""));` after  `holder.amount.setText("RM"+""+search.get(position).getUsed());`, app crashed.

**Error**

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "1.0"
            at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
            at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
            at com.example.tony.monthlyexpenses.adapter.ExpensesAdapter.getView(ExpensesAdapter.java:106)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2232)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`holder.progressBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(total+""));` This line is giving you an error. You trying to parse String which is "1.0" into Integer, but value 1.0 is float type.

Try like this:
Take Float value and round it. This will return Integer

`Math.round(Float.parseFloat(total+""))`

Answer (score 2):

Just change:

```
Integer.parseInt(total+"")
```

to:

```
(int) total
```

or, if you want to be more precise:

```
Math.round(total)
```

Comment: He can't directly coast String to int as total is String value

Comment: I assumed it's float or double because of the +""

Comment: And it actually is, since you can see total = budget - used, where budget and used are doubles

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace:
 `holder.progressBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(total+""));`

With:

`holder.progressBar.setProgress(Math.round(total));`

Answer (score 0):

The value `total` is either a `double` or a `float`, the `setProgress()` method takes an `int` as argument.

So you can do the following, change the type of `total` to an `int`,

Or use:

```
setProgress(Math.round(total));
```

The `Math.round` function can be used with a `double` or `float`, it will reproduce an `int` if you pass a `float` to it, or a `long` if you pass a `double` to it. The output will return the value which will round the input to the closest decimal.